# Embeded window dialog into Window Form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm using Straus7 API with C# and through an API. I can open a window dialog of the model but it opens like a popup dialog. How can I embed that windows dialog into my C# form? I don't want a popup dialog, how can I achieve this?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awUT9.png)
Thanks to @Mihail, i write this code and it work. My final code is:

```
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        St7.St7CreateModelWindow(1);
        St7.St7ShowModelWindow(1);
        St7.St7PositionModelWindow(1, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        St7.St7ShowWindowTopPanel(1);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////

        int temp = 0;
        St7.St7GetModelWindowHandle(1, ref temp);
        IntPtr hostHandle =  new IntPtr(temp);
        IntPtr guestHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle; 

        //SetParent(guestHandle, hostHandle);
        SetParent(hostHandle, guestHandle);
```

Now it need only some adjustment.

Comment: I think you can use the Windows Api method `SetWindowParent` and give the handle of the window and of the panel or container you need to be in.

Comment: Ok, it work! Thanl you so much. Multumesc!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following code :

```
    this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    Form Form = new Form();
    Form.MdiParent = this;
    Form.Show();
```